# Show that the subset $S$ in $\mathbb{R}_3$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the subset $S$ in $\mathbb{R}_3$ defined by $S=\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}_3 \text{ such that } a+b=c \}$ is a subspace.
I'm having trouble adapting the definition of subspace with the part $a+b=c$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: @Allison Note that the $3$ in $\Bbb R^3$ isn't an index -- it's an exponent.  That is $\Bbb R^3 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, where $\times$ denotes the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  In short: it's $\Bbb R^3$, not $\Bbb R_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show, that 
$$ S = \left\{ (a,b,c) \in \Bbb R^3 \; : \; a+b = c \right\} \subset \Bbb R^3$$
is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

First, note that $(0,0,0) \in S$, since $0 + 0 = 0$, so $S \neq \emptyset$.

Next, let $v_1 := (a_1, b_1, c_1), \, v_2 := (a_2, b_2, c_2) \in S$. We have to show, that $v_1 + v_2 = (a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2, a_3 + b_3) \in S$. Since $v_1 \in S$, we have $a_1 + b_1 = c_1$, and since $v_2 \in S$, we have $a_2 + b_2 = c_2$. So we see, that 
$$(a_1 + a_2) + (b_1 + b_2) = c_1 + c_2 \; ,$$
which means that 
$$ v_1 + v_2 = (a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2, c_1 + c_2) \in S \; .$$

Finally, let $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ and $v := (a,b,c) \in S$. We need to show, that $\alpha v \in S$. Since $a+b = c$, we have $\alpha a + \alpha b = \alpha c$, which means that 
$$ \alpha v = (\alpha a, \alpha b, \alpha c) \in S \; .$$

This shows, that $S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: $0 \in S$ is not a condition that needs to be shown separately since it follow from the last step of the proof.  While the step can be skipped, it is often useful for deciding *whether* a given set is a subspace.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, you're right, I just wanted to note, that $S \neq \emptyset$, because if $S = \emptyset$, it would not be a subspace.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that.  Well done.